# Magento Downloader not working

Tags: magento-1.7

In magento application , when i click on magento connect

it will goes to error page with url as :

```
http://mysite.com/downloader/?return=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Findex.php%2Fadmin%2F
```

How to overcome this issues?.

Answer (score 0):

After an upgrade of Fishpig / Magento WordPress Integration I was unable to access Magento connect Manager for about 2 months. I had to uninstall it through FTP (download the extension to get information about every file and folder in your Magento installation.)

After removing FishPig you will see a scary error but do not worry as you can just clean the cache using `agento-cleanup.php`.